# Ошибки при npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

**Как разобраться в этих ошибках?**

npm ERR! code EACCES

npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! path /home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/array-initial

npm ERR! dest /home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/.array-initial.DELETE

npm ERR! errno -13

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/array-initial' -> '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/.array-initial.DELETE'

npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/array-initial' -> '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/.array-initial.DELETE'] {

npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/array-initial' -> '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/.array-initial.DELETE'] {

npm ERR!     errno: -13,

npm ERR!     code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!     syscall: 'rename',

npm ERR!     path: '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/array-initial',

npm ERR!     dest: '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/.array-initial.DELETE'

npm ERR!   },

npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/array-initial' -> '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/.array-initial.DELETE'",

npm ERR!   errno: -13,

npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',

npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',

npm ERR!   path: '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/array-initial',

npm ERR!   dest: '/home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/.array-initial.DELETE',

npm ERR!   parent: 'start-tpl-html5-coding'

npm ERR! }

npm ERR!

npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.

npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user

npm ERR!

npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the

npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running

npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /home/nikolay/.npm/_logs/2019-11-18T19_48_02_582Z-debug.log

Comment: Прочитать (возможно со словарём) что написано в последних 10 строчках

Comment: Прочитал и раз 5 запускал. Толку ноль

Comment: Забыл добавить, что нужно ещё **понять**. Ну давайте начнём с простого: `sudo rm -r node_modules`, а потом `npm install`

Comment: Но не помогло!
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/array-initial
npm ERR! dest /home/nikolay/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding/node_modules/.array-initial.DELETE
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running command again as Administrator.

Comment: nikolay@LAPTOP-3M0TUBRF:~/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding$ rm -r node_modules/
nikolay@LAPTOP-3M0TUBRF:~/projects/start-tpl-html5-coding$ sudo npm i

Comment: Вы благополучно перепутали где писать `sudo`. И что, `rm -r` отработал без ошибок и после него не осталось папки `node_modules`?